# Animate AbsoluteLayout item in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The slider starts of like this.

```
<Slider x:Name = "one" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
```

I then want to animate it so it goes upwards and gets a bit wider so I then used this code snippet:

```
await one.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0.5, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1), 1500, Easing.CubicInOut)
```

When that code runs then the slider completely disappears from the screen.

Any idea how one can animate items that is being positioned by a absolutelayout?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouzaI am using Xamarin.Forms.Android. Not sure how to write out `show layout bounds` there

Comment: one.Bounds maybe?

Comment: I can find it now on my phone, how will this help the problem?

Comment: When the `LayoutTo` effect is running, you will see if the Slider is getting out of the screen or if it's too small to see. Then you can adjust what you need.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Ahh good tip! It gets put in the top left corner, super super super small.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouzaI tried ur layoutsuggestion but it did not change the outcome

Comment: Can you update the question describing or showing in which step you are now? Or did we get back on the drawing board?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Pretty much back to the drawing board. No real progress made. I could potentially use "ScaleTo" but that is not giving me the exact animation I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't clearly imagine what you expect as an effect, but I bet it's something like this:

```
var newBounds = new Rectangle(one.Bounds.X - 10, one.Bounds.Y -5, one.Bounds.Width + 20, one.Bounds.Height +10);
one.LayoutTo(newBounds, 1500, Easing.CubicInOut);
```

That will looks like this:

[image: Gif]

*I added an increase and decreased effect just to clarify*

Comment: Tried it very briefly this morning without success but i will try it more throughly when i get home! Exciting :)

Comment: Let me know if you get troubles. This solution I had tested and taken that screen capture as a gif to show how the effect looks like (It's alternating between the original size and the expanded one).

Comment: I just realized i never accepted ur answer. It works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task AnimateViewInAbsoluteLayout(View view, Rectangle rectAbsolute, Rectangle rectDest, uint time, Easing easing = null)
        { 
            await view.LayoutTo(rectDest, time, easing);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(view, rectAbsolute);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(view, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        }
```

usage:

```
AnimateViewInAbsoluteLayout(viewToMove, AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(viewDest), viewDest.Bounds, 250, Easing.Linear);
```